# Django html forms: obtain data using get request and pass on to the another view

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views, django-2.1

I am using two views in django: one for showing a form and get data and then use the data as an argument to the second view. But I could not quite figure this out as how to do it.

So far my views look like

```
class View1(View):

    def get(self, request):

        return render(request, 'example/view1.html')

class View2(View):

    def get(self, request, arg1):
        token = processData(arg1)
        context = {
            'word': token,
        }
        return render(request, 'example/view2.html', context)
```

I have my urls.py set up as

```
app_name = example 

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('', View1.as_view(), name='view1'), 
    path('view2/', View2.as_view(), name='view2'), 
    ]
```

Now in the template view1.html I have the following code

```
<form action="{% url 'example:view2 expected_argument %}" method="get">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <input id="key" type="text" name="key">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

what would be the 'expected_argument' in the template so that I can get the input form value from the view1.html template, and then pass it on to the View2.

Comment: you need to configure a url. see the docs for urls.py

Comment: My url is configured appropriately. For example, if I provide expected_argument='sample_text' it works smoothly. I have the following code on my urls.py

`app_name = example

urlpatterns = [
     path('', View1.as_view(), name='view1'),
     path('view2/', View2.as_view(), name='view2'),
]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "expected argument". Your view2 URL does not accept one, and it's not possible for a form to update its own URL like that anyway.

You don't need an argument there at all. Remove `arg1` from the signature of that `get` method, and get your data inside that function via `request.GET['key']`.